# apple-jdbc-web server

Tags: java, apache, jdbc, applet

I'm a BSc student in CIT. I have a project in which I want to use a Java applet and JDBC in a sort of host/client.

My applet is working properly on localhost, but when I deploy it on apache webserver I loose the JDBC connection.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use an applet with JSBC?
2. If yes how to do it?
3. Is there any web server in which to deploy applet and that supports jdbc connection?

My system: Fedora 8, NetBeans 6.5, XAMPP, MySQL.

Comment: I think you mean "apologies" not "desolations". Just for your information.

Comment: Could you say more about how you are losing the jdbc connection? Do you get an exception? If so, which exception. Can you provide the stack trace of the exception? You can look for this by opening up the applet console log.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running up against an issue with the Applet running in a sandbox, it can only communicate with the server from which it came - so if your database is on a different machine it can't be found.

A preferable architectural approach is to have your server do all the JDBC and communicate the information requested via HTTP to the client which is thinner dealing mainly presenting the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes its possible to use applet with jdbc.
2. Look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/AppletJDBC.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JDBCapplet.htm) and [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/applet.html) for possible ways of implementation.
3. Try googling for webservers, you will find tons of them, one lead is http://eatj.com/.

Rgds,

Aeon